# Math.cos(90°) = 6.123233995736766E-17

Tags: java, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Столкнулся с проблемой в `Math`:

```java
double a = 0.0;
double b = Math.toRadians(a);
System.out.println(Math.cos(b));
```

Вывод: `1.0`.

```java
double a = 90.0;
double b = Math.toRadians(a);
System.out.println(Math.cos(b));
```

Вывод: `6.123233995736766E-17`.

Почему Java подсчитывает 90 градусов неверно?

Answer (score 7):

Обратите внимание, программа вывела не просто `6.123233995736766`, а 6.123233995736766**E-17**.

Это представление (с «E») называется *научной нотацией*. В ней числа имеют вид:

> ±*mmmm*E±*pppp*

где:

- m — мантисса (эдакое базовое число);
- p — порядок (на сколько цифр сдвинуть запятую в мантиссе; плюс — направо, минус — налево).

Таким образом, 6.123233995736766E-17 превращается в 0.00000000000000006123233995736766.

Answer (score 3):

Так а все верно.

> 6.123233995736766E-17

это почти 0, такой ответ связан с [точностью представления чисел с плавающей точкой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008).

---

PS: Сравнивать double в этом случае нужно примерно так, если Вас устраивает такая точность...

```
boolean isEqual(double d1, double d2){
    return Math.abs(d1 - d2) < 1e-10;
}
```

Comment: Почти ноль - это `Double.MIN_VALUE`, а это - просто хреновый метод (`cos()`). Так то `6.123233995736766E-17` - не такое уж и маленькое число, если говорить о каких-то точный вычислениях. Ну а `Double.compare()` справедливо покажет, что `6.123233995736766E-17` больше нуля.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия да, спасибо, подрихтовал ответ =)

Comment: Этот метод, наверное, считается с помощью бесконечных сумм. Чтобы точность была больше, нужно больше слагаемых, к сожалению, тут только свой метод писать и остаётся.

Answer (score 3):

Метод `cos()` вычисляет косинус, используя [бесконечную сумму](http://edu.sernam.ru/book_sm_math1.php?id=130) (у меня нет инсайдерских данных, просто по-другому это реализовать проблематично: *P.S.). Чем больше слагаемых, тем точнее вычисления.

Примерно так он реализован:

```java
double cos(double x, int precision) {
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < precision; i++) {
        result += Math.pow(x,2*i)/factorial(2*i);
        i++;
        result -= Math.pow(x,2*i)/factorial(2*i);
    }
    return result;
}

ArrayList<Double> factorialCache = new ArrayList<>();

{
    factorialCache.add(1D);
}

double factorial(int n) {
    if (n < factorialCache.size()) return factorialCache.get(n);
    double result = factorialCache.get(factorialCache.size() - 1);
    for (int i = factorialCache.size(); i <= n; i++)
        factorialCache.add(result *= i);
    return result;
}
```

На достаточно небольших числах, порядка десяти, факториал начинает немыслимо быстро расти. Чтобы производить точные вычисления на очень больших и очень маленьких числах, необходимо вместо `double` использовать `BigDecimal`, но с ним вычисления происходят намного дольше, чем с `double`, поэтому разработчиками явы принято решение пожертвовать точностью взамен производительности. При желании вы можете сами написать более точный метод для определения косинуса.

При точности (`precision`) `12` (или `11`) метод возвращает `4.245771032544636E-17`, немного меньше, чем стандартный метод. Меньше при использовании `double` получить не получится.

P.S.: В принципе можно реализовать вычисление косинуса ещё и с помощью [формулы Эйлера о синусе и косинусе](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0), но там нужно реализовывать класс, представляющий комплексные числа. Ещё можно сохранить "транспортир" в виде массива косинусов при разных углах, но точность от этого будет страдать.